# Eval property and extra text on a button's text property

Tags: asp.net, button, binding

I'm using an asp Button like follows:

```
<asp:Button id="someButton" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Size") %>' />
```

This is great but before the Eval Property result I wanted to add the Text "Download " with possibly the units after it.

eg. Download 123KB.

Can someone please tell me how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it might be easier to set the text property of the button on the server in the page load event.

Comment: I agree.  The best way to do this is in the page load event.

someButton.Text = "Download " + size + "KB";

Answer (score 0):

insted of button use linkButton.
**asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink2" OnClick="HyperlinkSelectedCustomers_Click"   runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' ><%#Eval("selectedCustomers") %>/asp:LinkButton